# How to minimize the no of css

Tags: html, css, compression

Just like javascript compressor, i use the same technique for css. First, i merge all the file into a single file and then compressor. But, the behaviour of HTML is not same as earlier with   multiple css file. What is the best way to minimize the the no of CSS File?

Comment: Do you use an JavaScript compressor for CSS or is it a *dedicated* CSS compressor? If you use YUI Compressor, try the `--type css` commandline switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the order of loading you files into the merge script, like others have mentioned.
I found [Sprockets](http://getsprockets.org/) to be good tool for dependency management. It keeps track of changes in your files and outputs a single file, ready for compression. It will also work with your CSS files.

Answer (score 3):

Are you merging them into a single file in the proper order? Since CSS allows overriding earlier rules, you may need to be careful about which portion of the combined file comes before what other portions.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your HTML is valid. If your browser is in quirks mode, it may be using CSS that your compressor thinks is unneccessary.

Comment: Good point, but make it more general: In the line of 'check that the compressor doesn't throw away your hacks.'

Answer (score 1):

Could it be, that you merge, by mistake perhaps, also your print stylesheets into the main stylesheet? (Just a guess.)

If so, and you'd like to keep it that way, you can still do that by enclosing their content into:

```
@media print {
    /* content here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of your HTML generally should not change. If this does indeed happen, I'm guessing that you have conflicting rules that overwrite one another, and that the CSS files are not being merged in the same order as they were previously loaded.

Comment: @d. I keep the same order as earlier it was.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the CSS files are in the same folder, they are concatenated in the same order as they were loaded in the pages, and the resulting file is placed in the same folder as the original files, there should be no problem.

The order of the styles matter if they are conflicting, as the style last specified will take precedence.

The location of the files matter for any relative image URLs that you specify, as they are relative to the CSS file, not relative to the web page.